# Program not entering in if-else block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If i give input as 1 or 2, regardless of that program goes in default. Tried comparing input with "1" and 1 both. Same result.
My first Ruby program, plz excuse for naivety.

```
$choice

def getInfo
  puts "Info"
end 

def getMoreInfo
  puts "MoreInfo"
end


def switch
        if $choice == "1" #intentionally in ""
          getInfo
        elsif $choice == 2 #intentionally without ""
          getMoreInfo
        else
          puts "default"
        end
end


def callMainMenu
        puts "Choose the operation:"
        puts "[1] Get some Info"
        puts "[2] Get some moreInfo"
$choice=gets
$choice.chomp
end


callMainMenu
switch
```

Comment: Thank you so much Everyone :) It worked...choosing "bdon" as the answer since it was the first reply! Thank you All!!

Comment: as a matter of ruby style... just don't use globals `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the destructive version of `chomp` if you're going to assign it like that.

```
$choice.chomp!
```

Or

```
$choice = $choice.chomp
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug this, what I'd do is add `puts $choice.inspect` at the beginning of your `switch` method to see exactly what's in the variable. That said, I believe the problem here is that you're calling `$choice.chomp` instead of `$choice.chomp!`. The former will return the result, and the latter will change the variable in place.

Answer (score 2):

When you change `$choice.chomp` to `$choice.chomp!` and get rid of the `//` (change those to `#`), then you'll have something working. Keep refining it , it is not perfect yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$choice.chomp!`. chomp without ! does not alter $choice. It returns a new string. This a naming convention in Ruby.